# How to turn a <nav> with lists into a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, list, drop-down-menu, nav

I am having trouble turning my nav into a drop down menu. I have tried many ways, yet I am not able to turn my nav into a drop down menu. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. The solutions I am trying look like the guides I tried following. To no luck. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <button class="dropdown-menu">Menu</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Fighting%20Kites.html">Fighting Kites</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Membership.html">Membership</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav ul{
display: none;
}
nav ul:hover .dropdown-menu{
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try this

```css
nav ul{
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

nav:hover  ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <button class="dropdown-menu">Menu</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Fighting%20Kites.html">Fighting Kites</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Membership.html">Membership</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This will display the lists when you hover on the button.

Comment: Great, now if I could click those, it would be nice. :)

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, I already edited my answer. Kindly check it out .

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav ul{
display: none;
}
nav .dropdown-menu:hover ul{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <button class="dropdown-menu">Menu <ul>
        <li><a href="Fighting%20Kites.html">Fighting Kites</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="Membership.html">Membership</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
    </ul>
  </button>
</nav>
```

//thats all...